# Riccati equation $y'+\frac{y^2}{x}=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a Riccati equation:
$$y'+\frac{y^2}{x}=1$$
How can I solve it? Where do I begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[First]** :  Rewrite the ODE in the form of :
$$
y'(x)=p(x)+q(x)y(x)+r(x)(y(x))^2\implies y'=1-\frac{y^2}{x}
$$
Where $p(x)=1$, $q(x)=0$, and $r(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$

**[Second]** : Let $y(x)=-\frac{u'(x)}{r(x)u(x)}$, we obtain :
$$
r(x)u''(x)-\left(r'(x)+q(x)r(x)\right)u'(x)+p(x)(r(x))^2u(x)=0\implies-\frac{1}{x}u''+\frac{1}{x^{2}}u'+\frac{1}{x^{2}}u=0
$$
That is assuming $x\neq0$, we get :
$$
xu''-u'-u=0
$$
You can now proceed from here.